# PHP - Criar cookie com multiplos valores

Tags: php, cookies

Boa Tarde,

Estou criando um script que adicionara cookies a conta do utilizador.
O problema é que... Eu quero adicionar várias cookies por exemplo:

Se o utilizador clicar em adicionar no anuncio 1 ele vai criar uma cookie com o ID 1.
  Daqui a 2h, se o utilizador clicar no anuncio 10 ele vai adicionar mais 1 cookie, ficando assim com 2 cookies. A do ID 1 e a do ID 10.

Criei isto assim:

```
    if(isset($_GET['add_favorite'])) {

       $favorite_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, sanitize($_GET['add_favorite']));
       setcookie("fav_ads_ids", $favorite_id, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");           
    }
```

O problema é que ele simplesmente faz um UPDATE a cookie, e nao é isso que quero. Eu quero que criei viarias cookies para vários anuncios em favorito com o mesmo nome "fav_ads_ids".

Answer (score 2):

## Multipolos cookies com o mesmo índice

`json_encode()` faz a transformação do array php para string, fazendo assim podendo ser salvo no `cookie` que tem como requerimento um parametro *string*

`json_decode()` transforma o array em formato *string* para o formato *php*

```
if(isset($_GET['add_favorite'])) {
if(isset($_COKKIE['fav_ads_ids'])){ // verifica se o cokkie exite
    $ads = implode(',', json_decode($_COOKIE['fav_ads_ids'])); // organiza o array existente em: 1,2,3 
    $favorite_id = SELECT id FROM suaTabela WHERE id NOT IN ({$ads}) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 // faz a busca no sql de forma que remove os valores contidos na variavel $ads e ordana o resultado dinamico, selecionando apenas um para exibir
    $arr = json_decode($_COOKIE['fav_ads_ids']); // busca os valores do cokkie
}else{
    $favorite_id = SELECT id FROM suaTabela ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 // seleciona todos os campos do sql e ordana o resultado dinamico, selecionando apenas um para exibir
    $arr = []; // novo valor do cokkie
}
$arr[] = $favorite_id['id']; //adiciona o novo item no array
$arr = json_encode($arr); // prepara o array para ser salvo
setcookie("fav_ads_ids", $arr, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // salva o array
}
print_r($_COOKIE['fav_ads_ids']); // imprime os valores do array
```

[exemplo](https://ideone.com/LstNew)

Comment: agora só falta vc configurar a busca no sql para gerar os valores para o cookie

Comment: mas não é bem isso, é que eu nao quero adicionar logo o ID 1 ou 2, vai depender do utilizador. Se eu vier um Anuncio com ID ex: 3, eu add nos favoritos correcto. Horas depois eu vejo outro com ID diferente e meto add favoritos... entende? O utilizador nao vai escolher os 2 ID de seguida. Pois isto e um Sistema de Favoritos

Comment: Conteudo da Cookie: %7B%221%22%3A%22215%22%2C%222%22%3A%22215%22%7D

Como é que eu agora faço ECHO em ID do anuncio?

Comment: humm blz pera ai que vou refazer então, pois isso e a base... vou editar para você

Comment: pq e o seguinte se nao tem nada pronto a primeira coisa que vc tem que fazer e medir quantos anuncios tem na db, ai depois se ele não tiver nenhum da um aleatorio no numero total de anuncios, dps imprimir para o cliente e salvar o id que ja foi exibido, para não mostrar novament; correto?

Comment: sim isso, é exatamente isos

Comment: ao fazer decote, aparece Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in D:\xampp\htdocs\Superfacil_v1.3.7\inc\functions.php on line 1038

Comment: @RuiAlvez eae resolveu?

Comment: nao...penso precisart de um tutorial de como fazer Sistema de Favorito :S ta dificil

Comment: @RuiAlvez posta a pagina ai completa vou te da uma mão ai tu estuda ela

Comment: @RuiAlvez seu metodo de como ta buscando no mysql